# C - fseek() affecting the contents(structure) of a file when trying to update the records

Tags: c, struct, structure, file-handling, fseek

Not sure what is wrong the fseek() in this function as I am lead to believe that it is the cause for the problems with the incorrect output for my program.

```
   index = 0;
    present = 0;
    while(fread(&beverage, sizeof(struct beverages), 1, filepointer))
    {
        if(newFile == 0)
            break;

        printf("%s\n\n", beverage.bcode);
        getch();

        if(strcmp(_bev_name, beverage.bname) == 0)
        {
            printf("Inside if statement\n\n");
            getch();

            beverage.quantity = beverage.quantity + qty;
            beverage.qty_last_purchase = qty;


            priceOne = spent/qty;//Used to calculate the cost price for one beverage
            beverage.price = priceOne + (priceOne*0.10);//Calculation of sale price for beverage

            printf("%d\n\n", index);
            getch();

            fseek(filepointer,index*sizeof(struct beverages),SEEK_SET);
            fwrite(&beverage,sizeof(struct beverages),1,filepointer);

            present = 1;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            present = 0;
            index = index + 1;
        }

    }

    if(present == 0)
    {
        //Stores new beverage name
        strcpy(beverage.bname, _bev_name);

        //Creation of beverage code using the first two letters of beverage name and random 3 digit number
        srand(time(NULL));
        int ran_num = rand()%(999 + 1 - 100) + 100;
        char str[3];

        itoa(ran_num, str,10);

        beverage.bcode[0] = beverage.bname[0];
        beverage.bcode[1] = beverage.bname[1];
        beverage.bcode[2] = str[0];
        beverage.bcode[3] = str[1];
        beverage.bcode[4] = str[2];
        beverage.bcode[5] = '\0';

        beverage.qty_last_purchase = qty;
        beverage.quantity = qty;
        priceOne = spent/qty;//Used to calculate the cost price for one beverage
        beverage.price = priceOne + (priceOne*0.10);//Calculation of sale price for beverage

        fwrite(&beverage, sizeof(struct beverages), 1, filepointer);

    }
```

The first part of the code loops through an existing file to find the matching beverage code and then to update the quantity and price of the beverage but what has been happening is that it is affecting the other structures in the file.

[Shows how beverages are displayed when they are first added to file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MERdS.png)

[Shows how the list of beverages are affected after the records are updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6D3RY.png)

To be noted I chose to update the first beverage in the first picture but as you can see it affects the second beverage record.

EDIT : The definition of the struct beverages

```
struct beverages
{
    char bname[NAME_LIMIT];
    char bcode[MAX_SIZE];
    int quantity;
    int qty_last_purchase;
    float price;
} beverage;
```

Comment: I cannot see what's wrong with your code, but what I do see is that you are combining sequential file access (relying on the file updating its internal file position after reading/writing) with random file access (invoking `fseek()`.)  This can lead to big trouble.  Try invoking `fseek()` every single time to seek to a specific record index before reading/writing a record.

Comment: @MikeNakis could you give me an example if possible...I'm some what of a novice at C so I am not quite sure how to go about what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

Although you don't show the most important part of your code: the definition of `struct beverages`, I strongly believe you are barking up the wrong tree and your problems have nothing to do at all with `fseek()`.

It appears `struct beverages` doesn't store the beverage's name literal characters in `beverage.bname`, but a pointer to them instead.

Thus, you most likely save and retrieve pointers instead of values. These pointers point to meaningless data once restored. Either store *all* of your data *inside* of your data records or make yourself familiar with the concepts of serialization and deserialization.

Comment: Made edit showing the definition for struct beverages

Comment: o.k., looks good. Next thing to look into is your `itoa()` usage. That looks strange.

Comment: Should I use sprintf instead ?

Comment: either that or fix what you have. You expect a three-digit number which will use at least four bytes when converted to a string, but only reserve three for it.

Comment: doesn't really change anything